# Promise subclassing with properties

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, es6-promise

Is it possible to subclass Promise so that custom properties can be added that survive subsequent calls to `.then()` / `.catch()` etc?

Calls to these methods return a new Promise class which loses the context.

For example:

```js
var myPromise = Promise.resolve();
myPromise.foo = 'Foo!'; // Mutate the promise base (this works fine)

var myPromise2 = myPromise.then(()=> 'result!'); // Attach a thennable
console.log(myPromise2.foo) // should = 'Foo!', but myPromise2 is actually just {} after any promise call
```

Comment: Yes, by overriding the `then` method to copy your property to the new instance, but why would you want to do that?

Comment: `'result!'`  is not a thenable?

Comment: The outer problem is a long running process that needs to pass context details. I would like the promise to be decorated with properties accessible from the promise object.

Comment: For example if this was a wrapper for Node's `child_process.spawn` process executor the promise would resolve when the program terminates but I could pass things like the current process ID, stdout/err buffer contents etc. as properties on the (eventually resolving) promise

Comment: Don't. Use a wrapper around the promise, [composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance).

Comment: That would presumably mean return an object with a promise sub-item, what I'm after here is a function which returns a promise that _may_ be decorated with optional functionality.

Comment: Yes, I understood what you wanted, but I advice against decorating promise instances. Especially if you then want to write a function that takes the process executor results, processes them, and returns a normal promise to the caller: you could not use promise chaining if the `then` method created another promise with custom properties but you don't want to leak details such as the process id.